# How to continue with the merge if all the conflicts can be resolved by checking out theirs?

Tags: git, merge

I'm merging my files up to a remote repo.

I get merge conflicts when I push it up. Weirdly, these are all files I never touched in my branch (but thats probably for another post).

I `git checkout --theirs` to all these files.

Then I `git commit`.

But I am unsure what to do next.

If I `git push` I just get another merge error with the same files.

`git merge --continue` doesn't work on my version of git.

Would any one know what I should be doing next?

Comment: Then I wonder which version you are using...? And why.

Comment: You should find why there are changes. They do not happen by themselves. "thats probably for another ticket" - note that there is no such thing as "merge separated file/diff", when you merge it all merges. If you decide to discard meaningful changes with `checkout --theirs` at that moment then later you will have to spend extra efforts recovering them to use.

Comment: @kowsky Version 1.7.9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well @sajib-khan is correct in what the textbook procedure for your case is
but I sense there is more going on here.

First, please note that in Git, it's impossible to get *merge* conflict
*on push.*  The only case which might prevent the piece of history with which
you're trying to update a remote branch from doing so is the fact your piece
of history does not *fully contain* the current history of that remote branch¹.
To explain it in other words, if the branch you intend to update ends in
this sequence of commits

```
…→C→D→E
```

you can not update it with the piece of history which ends up like

```
…→C→D→X→Y→Z
```

because your piece only contains `C` and `D` but does not contain `E`.
Pushing

```
…→C→D→E→X→Y→Z
```

instead would go just fine.

So it may be that your problem is trivial and just while you were busy
merging someone has managed to update the remote branch with more commits
and you naturally need to reconcile your work with the remote work again.

> Let me stress this again: Git *never* merges remotely—it only updates
>   branches and tags with what was sent.  When doing so, it ensures that when
>   a branch is updated, it's updated "additively"—that is,
>   the new changes are only ever appended to the series of commits
>   currently pointed at by the branch about to be updated.

Second, the "weird" case where you only have "non yours" files marked as
being in conflict might indicate you are facing a EOL mess: say, someone
changed sole `LF`s (Unix-style end-of-line marks) to `CR+LF` sequences
(Windows EOL marks) and committed the change; for you this will look as
whole-file conflicts because, naturally, every line in those files was
changed.  Hence I'd try to investigate whether that's indeed the case.

Third, please don't consider working with a shared remote repository
as some fight you have to win no matter how.  If you have a werid conflict,
as you do, stop and investigate.

Start with `git fetch` and then inspect the commits which have appeared
on the remote branch since the point where it and your local branch were
diverged.  Say, if we're talking about "master", do

```
git log origin/master ^master
```

which means «show me what's on the "master" branch just fetched from the
"origin" repo which is not on my local "master" branch».
See what those commits change.

If you cannot fathom the reason for the conflict, reach for whoever is in
charge of that repo or the project it hosts and bring this issue before them
to solicit a solution.

Trying to sidestep a problem leads to cases like [those](https://randyfay.com/content/avoiding-git-disasters-gory-story) which is bad for everyone.

---

¹ Well, except for custom repository hooks which are programs which are run
by Git at specific points in data exchange and can be used to verify incoming
data in any way and fail the ongoing push operation, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Its appreciated.